# How to disable Bootstrap's html,body attribute overriding?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**Imports**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic" rel="stylesheet">
```

I defined main properties for my css classes as a parent class like below.Especially to make it easier for media queries.

```
html,body{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #555;
    font-family:'Lato' ,'Arial',sans-serif;
    font-weight:300; 
    font-size:20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

But bootstrap overrides all these properties.For example I have code below but doesn't come with 300 font-weight.Instead of it,comes with 500 font-weight.

```
  <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>Goodbye junk food.<br>Hello super healthy meals.</h1>
              </div>
          </div>
```

I want to specify font-weight through parent class which has 300 in my example like below

```
h1{
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: 90%;
}
```

But it doesn't work bootstrap overrides everything

Comment: import your styles below bootstrap.css

Comment: Its already like that

Comment: You do realise that this is how CSS works, styles cascade. So if something like `container` has `font-weight` defined, that will overrule what is set on `html,body`. There are plenty of ways to override what Bootstrap has set, either by making your selector more specific, or the use of `!important`, which isn't recommended.

Comment: I know there are some ways.I could've set property `.container{font-weight:300} ` for example.But it wouldn't be parent class like `html,body{}.` I need more proper way

Comment: @putvande's advice is the second thing

Comment: In bootstrap has default `font-weight: bold;` for H1 tag. If you are defining in html/body tag then it will never worked. If you need to specify same style for all element then use `* {your css style here}`.

Answer (score -1):

> In your index.html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Put your styles below bootstrap.css import. Last ones overrides styles above.

> **Edit**

You should override specific types again. If it were what you thought; your

```
color: #555;
```

should override all color classes in bootstrap.

```
html,body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #555;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:'Lato' ,'Arial',sans-serif;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.container, 
h1 {
    font-weight:300; 
}
```

**OR**

You can customize and download bootstrap.css

- [bootstrap.build](https://bootstrap.build/)
- [bootstrapcustomizer](http://www.bootstrapcustomizer.com/)

Comment: Mine is already as you said.I updated my question and added imports

Comment: You can add body .container, body .h1 to your css tags and override bootstrap's container class. Your class added to body but bootstrap's .container styles overrides it.